# HQL Injection Question

Tags: security

This question popped into my head after reading [this](https://www.trustwave.com/en-us/resources/blogs/spiderlabs-blog/hql-injection-exploitation-in-mysql/) article.

However, the more I read about this topic,  the more it seems like a Dynamic SQL security issues. So i have 2 questions mainly:

- Is there really any difference between this and a Dynamic SQL query that allows injections?
- Why would there be a language like HQL that goes through Hybernate (MySQL) to get translated to SQL while using inconsistent character escape marks? It seems counter intuitive. Maybe i missed something.